# Is there a term for songs that have a “surprise change” in their rhythm?

Tags: terminology, rhythm, meter

There are many songs that begin with a repeating beat/instrumental that implies a certain rhythm (let’s call it “Rhythm A”), but then when a later instrument enters the song, it turns out that the song *actually* has “Rhythm B”, into which A is interleaved/mixed.

I notice this a lot with albums I hear for the first time — where I’m unaware of Rhythm B for the first 10–20 seconds — and it’s a neat surprise to have what I *assumed* was Rhythm A turn out to be a component of a pretty-different Rhythm B.

One example of this is the opening to [Luvofbahia by Wilczynski](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lskqtBgFlTw).

Is there a term for this?

Comment: ah man i love it. once the bass comes in it flips on its head, but now when i go back i can only hear it way it is with the bass.  do you happen to know if that is a sample (the guitar)?

Comment: soul coughing "white girl" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WlXipLy6nI is a good example. also check out this video about radiohead's "videotape": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_IHotHxIl8  however, i don't know the name of this technique.

Comment: Does the opening to Beethoven's V count?  Practically all non-orchestra members think the first notes are on downbeats.

Answer (score 0):

It’s apparently called “Turn the Beat Around” https://music.stackexchange.com/a/21984/51932

(Thanks to @leftaroundabout for the suggestion!)